# scss function for animation keyframes

Tags: css, function, sass, css-animations

i would like to do a reusable sass function that makes it easy for me to write a `@keyframes` css animation without writing too much code but I'm not sure how to go about it, especially the math part.

i have a div containing a single background image with this css

```
height: 100vh;
width: 8000px;
```

this background image is composed of 25 frames. so each frame is 320px wide.

the animation should `translateX()` the div by multiple of 320px every 4%, so something like this:

```
@keyframes animation {
    0% {
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    4% {
        transform:translateX(-320px);
    }
    8% {
        transform:translateX(-640px);
    }

    ...
}
```

i would like to make a function of this but I'm new to scss functions and i really don't know where to start. if someone could give me a hint that would be great!

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a steps timing function solve your request ?

Answer (score 1):

Could be better (modularise) but here is for you;

```
@mixin deneme($i){
  @for $i from 0 through 100/$i {
    #{$i * 4}% {
      transform:translateX(#{-320 * $i});
    } 
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think this one is a bit better.

```
@mixin deneme($increase, $angle){
  @for $x from 0 through 100/$increase {
    #{$x * $increase }% {
      transform:translateX($angle * $x);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you give yourself a chance?
https://gist.github.com/egemenu/94afc1c20318c811e3656ecd5cb6a936