# how to use scss function or mxin to generate key frame animation

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations, scss-mixins

I use named keyframe animations and I want to save myself some writing. I have seen this [SO Question regarding scss keyframe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350940/scss-function-for-animation-keyframes) But I feel like its not to helpful (or Im to stupid to understand)

I have tried a couple variations of

```
$green: limegreen;

@mixin pulse-animation($name, $color) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px rgba($color, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px rgba($color, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0);
    }
  }
}
.my-element {
  animation: @include pulse-animation("green", $green) 2s infinite;
}
```

I would also prefer to not have to pass a name into this mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [here](http://zerosixthree.se/8-sass-mixins-you-must-have-in-your-toolbox/) an interesting situation where first you create an animation with a keyframe mixin and then you use another mixin to include that animation (see ***4. Animations and keyframes***).

However, if you don't want to include 2 mixins because *you want to save yourself some writing*, another idea could be to create all keyframe animations you need using a simple map loop:

```
$colors:(
 "green": limegreen,
 "black": black,
 "white": white /*here you can add all colors you need*/
);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px rgba($color, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px rgba($color, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0);
    }
  }
}

.my-element {
  animation: green 2s infinite;
}
```